# entityManager.merge doesn't update data

Tags: java, merge, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to do a simple update of an existing entity in the database using entitymanager.merge but it doesn't make changes on the database.

Here is my code:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "tirGen", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 100)
public class User implements Serializable {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_SEQ", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID")
private long              id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "VALEUR_STATUT", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private String            status;
// GETTERS and Setters
}
```

where I'm calling merge (If I merge a new entity without Id it works by with Id it doesn't make changes)

```
// Entity manager is already injected
final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
try {
  if (entityManager == null) {
    throw new RollbackException("Unable to obtain a transactional EntityManager");
  }

  final EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

  if (entityTransaction == null) {
    throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException("Unable to obtain a EntityTransaction");
  }

  // Ouverture de la transaction
  entityTransaction.begin();
  entityManager.flush();
  entityManager.clear();

  if (entityTransaction.isActive()) {               
    User user2850 = entityManager.find(User.class, 2850L);
    user2850.setStatus("NewValue");
    User mergedUser = entityManager.merge(user2850);

    // when I debug on mergedUser I get status = newValue
    entityManager.flush();
    // Commit de la transaction
    entityTransaction.commit();
    // No modification in the database the user with Id 2850 have the old status
```

As I mentioned, it works when merging a new entity (and I tried to update another attribute but it still not working)

Comment: Note that since you load `user2850` inside the transaction the entity should be attached and thus merging is not necessary. Besides that, I have no experience using `EntityTransaction` but from the JavaDocs it seems to be subset of the database transaction. Did you commit that one as well and check for changes/errors etc. afterwards?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did commit the transaction and there is no errors, I did a workaround by using a namedquery instead of the merge method (it works em.createnamedquery("update X set x.attri = :param...").